# Property 'items' does not exist on type '[]'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, axios, react-context

So I am working on this project to learn typescript and I don't know how to solve it so I came here if somebody can explain what is an error and how to fix I would be grateful for the rest of my life :D

context.tsx

```
import React, {createContext,ReactNode,ReactPortal,useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { AnyMxRecord } from 'dns';
import database from '../database';
import { string } from 'yargs';



 
const top250Movies = createContext<[]>([
]);

const MoviesContext: React.FC<any> = ({children}) => {
    const [top250 , setTop250 ] = useState<any>('');

    if(top250 == ''){
    setTop250(database);
    }

  
  return (
    <top250Movies.Provider value={top250}>{children}</top250Movies.Provider>
  )
}

export default MoviesContext

export { top250Movies}
```

Homepage.tsx

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { top250Movies } from '../context/context'
import Footer from '../layouts/Footer'
import Navbar from '../layouts/Navbar'
import '../styles/Homepage.css'

function Homepage() {

    let backendData = useContext(top250Movies);
 

 if(backendData !== null){
        if(Array.isArray(backendData)){
            console.log(backendData.items.map((item: any) =>{ return item}));
        }
       
    }


  return (
    <div className='Homepage'><Navbar/> <div className="Homepage-content">Homepage</div>  <Footer/></div>
  )
}

export default Homepage
```

Expected output from backend data is object that in it has an object with array of movies e.g. backendData:{titles:[array]}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider modifying the code so that it's a self-contained [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted into a standalone IDE. Right now it depends on third-party/private types/values, so I can't easily work on it.  Unless those external dependencies are actually relevant to the question you're asking, it's better to remove them from your example.  If you *do* need them, then it would be helpful for you to provide definitions for them. The easier it is for others to play around with your code, the more likely it is that you'll get a useful answer.

Comment: If you do decide to [edit] the code this way and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`backendData` is an array you can `map()` directly on it !

```
if(backendData !== null){
  if(Array.isArray(backendData)){
      console.log(backendData.map((item: any) =>{ return item}));
  }        
}
```

Comment: But there is array in it that i want to access it, I edited the post so it is clear what i mean

Comment: I see i didn't explain well so origanlly the backendData is object that holds key value pairs and i need to access its second key items which holds an array